# Pig: Filter multi-column table on Set

Tags: filter, nlp, apache-pig, token, apache-datafu

I have the following inputs:

```
input = LOAD '$in_data' USING PigStorage('\t', '-schmea') AS (
   uid:chararray,
   pid:int,
   token:chararray
);
stpwrd = LOAD '$stpwrd' USING PigStorage('\t', '-schema') AS (
   token:chararray
);
```

My goal can be summarized in the following pseudo-code:

```
output = FILTER input BY NOT IN(input.token, stpwrd);
```

, which ideally gives rows in the `input` table whose `input.token` field is not in `stpwrd`.

I checked the `SetDifference()` UDF in `datafu` ([link](https://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/)), but I am not sure if that will do the job, since it seems to require both table to be singleton, while my `input` table has multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this objective using RIGHT join and filtering those records which are there in stpwrd, an example below illustrates the usage.

**Input : input_data**

```
uid1    1   token1
uid2    2   token2
uid3    3   token3
```

**Input : stpwrd**

```
token1
token2
```

**Pig Script :**

```
    input_data = LOAD 'input_data' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (
   uid:chararray,
   pid:int,
   token:chararray
);

stpwrd = LOAD 'stpwrd' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (
   token:chararray
);

output_data = JOIN stpwrd BY token RIGHT, input_data BY token;

req_data = FILTER output_data BY stpwrd::token IS NULL;
```

**Output : req_data**

```
(,uid3,3,token3)
```

Project required fields from req_data alias.

Comment: Wouldn't inner join require the token to be in both table? It seems like you are doing set intersection instead of set subtraction. Am I wrong?